# the length of scrollbar of flex parent is shorter the length of child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    [parent] {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      overflow: auto;

      & > [child] {
        flex: 1;
        align-self: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 2px solid green;
        & > [content] {
          max-width: 720px;
          min-width: 400px;
          flex: 1;
          border: 2px solid blue;

          & > header,
          & > main,
          & > footer {
            height: 200px;
            border: 2px solid red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div parent>
    <div child>
      <div content>
        <header>header</header>
        <main>main</main>
        <footer>footer</footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm trying to make html for popup content considering overflow and scroll.

the problem is the length of scroll-y of the flex parent is shorter than the length of the children of the parent, which makes some part of child invisible when scrollbar appears.

i can't figure out how can i fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add size constraints to `[parent]` like `max-width` and `max-height` to prevent it grow larger than viewport.
2. Set `flex-direction` to `column` for `[parent]` to match the desired content orientation.
3. Add `width: fit-content` to `[child]` and `[content]` to make them grow when content are too large.

## Example

```js
// spam text as normal page content
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let spam_text =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim. Volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit. Vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia at. Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Eu sem integer vitae justo. Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec.";
  document.getElementById("my-content").textContent = spam_text.repeat(30);
});
```

```css
.text-grey {
  color: rgb(188, 188, 188);
}


/* popup style */
[parent] {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  &>[child] {
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: fit-content;
    &>[content] {
      border: 2px solid blue;
      width: fit-content;
      &>header,
      &>main,
      &>footer {
        min-width: 120vw;
        min-height: 50vh;
        border: 2px solid red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- content -->
<div id="my-content" class="text-grey"></div>

<!-- popup -->
<div parent>
  <div child>
    <div content>
      <header>header</header>
      <main>main</main>
      <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. sadly, i already tried [parent] with "flex-direction: column". it fixed overflow y but the same problem happens in overflow x.

Comment: I have update my answer, but I am not quite sure if this is what you are looking for since I use overflow on `[content]` instead of `[parent]`, that me know if there are any more requirement. If possible, update your original question may help you get desired answer as well!

Comment: thanks for suggesting other approach, but what i want is scrolling parent

Comment: I think I might have found the solution. So I update my answer again, it makes `[content]` and `[child]` grow when things are too large, and `[parent]` will always have a size that are smaller than your viewport.